# Mock Mongoose Objects after populate call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocking, sinon

I am trying to mock a populate call and I would like to mock to return mongoose objects, not plain JS objects.

```
sandbox.mock(BookModel)
  .expects('populate')
  .yields(null, [
    new BookModel({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: 'Mock Book',
      authorIds: [{
        name: 'Foo',
      }]
    })
  ]);
```

With schemas:

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  authorIds: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author'}],
});

var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
});
```

However mongoose is preventing my test from creating the mock object with a mock populated author as mongoose is probably checking that the authorIds array is an array of object ids.

Has anyone used sinon to mock a populated field like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to insert something in the array after the creation of the mongoose object. Direct assignment of the array also doesn't work, so you'll need to loop through for multiple items.

```
var book = new BookModel({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: 'Mock Book',
      authorIds: []
  });

book.authorIds[0] = {
        name: 'Foo'
      };

sandbox.mock(BookModel)
  .expects('populate')
  .yields(null, [book]);
```